# Cannot get my images to fade in right sequence with jquery

Tags: jquery, fade

Please take a look at what I have done so far (with a little help from the good folk here!)

http://www.justthisdesign.co.uk/

I have the three banner images fading in, followed by the two in the left column, and finally the one in the right column.

However, the client wants the word "Projects" to fade in first, followed by each of the images in the left column, then "and", then "Properties", followed by the image in the right column.

I can get the sequence right, just about, by changing the .delay() value in each of the three divs but the pacing is impossible to get right.

Should I be using a different technique entirely in order to have more control? Obviously the client has no idea how much work this "simple request" involves!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

give each element an id, including the tags that hold the banner, then use the callback function for fadeTo to call each element once at a time, after the previous has finished, something like

```
$('#banner1').fadeTo(1000,1,function(){
  $('#banner2').fadeTo(1000,1,function(){
    $('#banner3').fadeTo(1000,1,function(){
    });
  });
});
```

The syntax, according to http://api.jquery.com/fadeTo/ is

```
.fadeTo( duration, opacity [, callback] )
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to trigger the fade in after document load.. Also trigger the next animation after the first one has finished

Example

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('#project_banner').fadeIn('slow', function(){
        //This is called after fade in 
        $('#project_and_banner').fadeIn('slow',function(){
           // And so on
        });   
     });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can specify callback, this callback function will be called when a function finishes its work

```
  $('#one').fadeIn('slow', function() {
     $('#two').fadeIn('slow',function(){
             $('#three').fadeIn();
       });
  });
```

here first it will fadeIn #one, then #two and then #three

Comment: Thanks. So, I need to make each image have it's own div?

Answer (score 0):

Try this **[Demo](http://jsbin.com/iwoxal/6)**

[DEMO CODE](http://jsbin.com/iwoxal/6/edit)

This is the simple jQuery for it

```
var mySequence=["one","two","three","four","five","six"];
$.each(mySequence,function(i){
  $("." + mySequence[i]).delay(1000*i).fadeTo(1000,1);
});
```